# Embed a URL in a simple http request

Tags: httprequest

I'm making a simple http request that looks something like this:

```
https://example.com/api/chat.postMessage?text=This%20should%20be%20a%20link
```

What this does is posts a message to our internal chat service. The `text=` is the text that gets posted to the chat channel. What I'd like is to embed a hyperlink here so that when the message is posted, "This should be a link" will actually link to an http link. Is this at all possible? Thanks!

Comment: There is a lot left out of this question - how is the chat rendered? Can it support HTML? Do you control the server? You could solve this on the server or the client. It all depends.

Comment: Yeah, after I wrote this I realized that it all depends on the rendering. We use Slack if that helps at all.

Comment: Are you wanting to post both the link and the link text ("click here" and "http://www...") Or just have the URL be a link?

Comment: The link would be something like "http://ourserver/browse/12345 and the text would be "Click <12345> to go to the issue." (where <12345> is the actual link)

Comment: Slack supports Markdown formatting - I'd suggest looking at this https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting and http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're working with the Slack API? The following two links could be helpful:

- [the chat.postmessage method](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)
- [testing the method call](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/test)

To encode the following text...

```
"go to http://www.google.com/"
```

...it seems that you would send a request to the following URL:

```
.../api/chat.postMessage?text=go%20to%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F
```